# Style of MediaElement in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

How can I change style of sample `MediaElement`:

[image]

For example how can I change the background.

Code:

```
<MediaElement AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" x:Name="media" MediaEnded="Media_MediaEnded" AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" IsMuted="False" Volume="0.5"/>
```

Comment: Whats the code of your `MediaElement`? Did you used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx)

Comment: No i'm using AreTransportControlsEnabled in windows 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can change the colors by overriding the default colors in the App.  Note this would apply now for *all* MediaElement controls with transport controls, but it is possible.  In your App.xaml you would provide overrides for these values like this:

```
  <Application.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Blue" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#26FFFFFF" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF000000" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaControlPanelVideoThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaControlPanelAudioThemeBrush" Color="#FF000000" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaDownloadProgressIndicatorThemeBrush" Color="#38FFFFFF" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaErrorBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF000000" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediaTextThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
  </Application.Resources>
```

This would give you a visual like this:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do not want to write your own controlpanel with play-pause-stop controls, you can not change the background of this `MediaElement` rendered controlpanel because it is an overlay of the video and is designed to look [MS/Windows8 conform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aretransportcontrolsenabled).

Note: This controlpanel is also invisible if you do not mouse-over the video.

Comment: is there any way to tell if the control panel is visible or not? IE: has it faded away or is it showing?