# media element and style

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

In my wp8 app i use media element i create buttons to play stop pause.Are there any media player controller that i dont have to create buttons and styles (i mean ready to use) because i have to set a lot of features and styles if windows has some thing ready to use it will save me a lot of codding 
also i saw something in stack-overflow .In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507842/style-of-mediaelement-in-windows-8-1) example that media element is windows object or it is designed by user

Comment: Only the functions can be inbuilt but not the UI. In any media element you have to create all the designing part.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the MediaPlayerLauncher control
see the msdn page for more details
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394004(v=vs.105).aspx